# Trigger on BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE fired once or twice?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I have created the following trigger;

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER material_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON materials
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_proc ();
```

I'm struggling to understand when `my_proc` will be run on an upsert query, such as the below:

```sql
--UPSERT
INSERT INTO materials (id, col)
VALUES (1, 1)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
col='x'
```

If I'm running the upsert, am I right to think that:

- in the case of an `INSERT` it will be run once
- in the case of an `UPDATE` it will be run twice

Then logically if I ran this `AFTER` the upsert I would ensure that the `my_proc` was triggered only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger is, infact fired **twice** in the case that the `UPDATE` is carried out.  This can be demonstrated using the follwing:

```sql
-- create table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (uuid int unique);
-- create function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION print_function ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $body$
    BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Starting';
    RAISE NOTICE 'METHOD: %' , TG_OP;
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
    
    $body$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- create trigger function
CREATE TRIGGER example_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON example
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE print_function ();
--  upserts
INSERT INTO example(uuid) VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT(uuid) DO UPDATE SET uuid=5;
INSERT INTO example(uuid) VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT(uuid) DO UPDATE SET uuid=5;
```

which gives output:

```
NOTICE:  Starting
NOTICE:  METHOD: INSERT             -- Populated with inital value
NOTICE:  Starting
NOTICE:  METHOD: INSERT             -- Fired a first time for insert (can't insert as exists)
NOTICE:  Starting
NOTICE:  METHOD: UPDATE             -- Fired a second time for update
INSERT 0 1
```